# Change default login user for Linux from root

Tags: linux, login, root, useradd, autologin

I've been working with Linux for awhile and was wondering how I could go about changing the default login user. The whole time I've used Ubuntu, I've been logging in as the root node, as bad as that is. It does it automatically upon startup. Running Ubuntu in Windows Terminal with WSL.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/816732/how-to-change-default-user-in-wsl-ubuntu-bash-on-windows-10 this might help you.

Comment: That did the trick. Had to create/source .profile into my home user directory, because I lost my colors, but all is well now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/816732/how-to-change-default-user-in-wsl-ubuntu-bash-on-windows-10

Went to the above link, and just went into cmd.exe and did:
ubuntu2004 config --default-user

This caused a secondary issue where I lost my colors on the terminal, but that was resolved with:

[Changed default user and now colors don't work Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/696954/changed-default-user-and-now-colors-dont-work-ubuntu/696955#696955)

Answer (score -2):

1. `sudo nano /etc/passwd`
2. Scroll down to your user and change the numbers for user id and group both to 0.
   Example:

   ```
   User:x:0:0:................
   ```

Be aware as this may result to unstable OS in some distros, or it may cause that some apps stop working.

Comment: I used it with Lubuntu and worked. Also, Parted Magic (Slackware based) is configured this way.

Comment: No, no, no! This changes your user account to be effectively the same as root, which removes just about all protections the system can otherwise give you from shooting yourself in both feet