# Changed default user and now colors don't work Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, users, colors

Working in Ubuntu, windows terminal, WSL, using Linux:

So I recently asked two questions:

1. How to bring the colors back to the terminal for a new user
2. How to change the default user

I solved the first question by creating /home//.bashrc, which didn't previously exist. Copied .bashrc from /etc/skel, and bam, it worked.
But then, I solved question 2. Just went into cmd.exe and did: ubuntu2004 config --default-user

And my default login is my new user. But now, the terminal is flat white text again! What can I do to get my colors back without having to source /home//.bashrc every time?

Thanks y'all.

Comment: Bingo, that did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: OK so I guess I should turn it into an answer ...

Comment: oh shoot SORRY, I appreciate it. 

Answer (score 2):

WSL starts an interactive login shell; by default, that reads ~/.profile (or ~/.bash_profile if it exists and your user's login shell is set to bash) in preference to ~/.bashrc.

In Ubuntu, the default ~/.profile then sources ~/.bashrc (if it detects that the shell is bash) so that you get the same environment as an interactive non-login shell.

So what's missing is that you need to copy `/etc/skel/.profile` to your new user's home directory as well as `/etc/skel/.bashrc`

Note that if you'd used `adduser` to create the new user, files in `/etc/skel` would normally have been copied to the new user's home directory by default.

Answer (score 0):

## wsl ubuntu 20.04 if you want to set color to root user.

## xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;; #line number 33 in my case.

```
xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;; #add this line in .bashrc
```